# How can I repeat a def function in Canvas?

Tags: python, function, canvas, repeat, tkinter-canvas

I want this def function to repeat itself as soon as the ball hits the ground (border of the window)
I tried using **if**, **for loop** and **while:**, but I wasn't able to make it work. I'm a beginner so maybe I'm just making stupid mistakes. Thanks for the help.

```
import tkinter
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=600, height=600)
canvas.pack()

def ball():
    canvas.delete('all')
    global y
    canvas.create_oval(x - 5,y - 5,x + 5,y + 5, fill = 'red')
    y = y + 2
    if y < 600:
        canvas.after(2, ball)
y = 0
x=300
ball()
```

**TL;DR**: I want to repeat a def function in Python after a certain event.

Comment: Your `ball()` function already seems to be repeating, but it also seems to *stop* repeating after the `oval` gets to the bottom. Did you want it to do something different at that time?

Comment: I want the ball() function to repeat itself as soon as the ball gets to the bottom, but I just can't repeat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to reset the `y` value:

```py
import tkinter
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=600, height=600)
canvas.pack()

def ball():
    canvas.delete('all')
    global y
    canvas.create_oval(x - 5,y - 5,x + 5,y + 5, fill = 'red')
    y = y + 2
    if y >= 600:
        y = 0   # Restart y from 0 again
    canvas.after(2, ball)
y = 0
x=300
ball()
```

Answer (score 0):

I implement a situation with python to show you how you can use the `while` loop and also using `return` for your functions to exit the loop after some event.
It's just an example for better understanding the answer. And do not use global variables in your code. It's just for the example.

```
a = 100

def count_down():
  global a
  a -= 1
  if a > 0:
    return True
  return False


in_the_loop = True

while(in_the_loop):
  in_the_loop = count_down()
  print(a)
```

Maybe this snippet will give some idea about your case to how to exit from the `base` function by simply adding `return` to that.